# Create a function that accepts a function and returns a function with timestamps

Tags: javascript, object, callback, arguments, key

Create a function `dateStamp` that accepts a function and returns a function. The returned function will accept whatever arguments the passed-in function accepts and return an object with a `date` key whose value is today's date (not including the time) represented as a human-readable string (see the Date object for conversion methods), and an `output` key that contains the result from invoking the passed-in function.

My code below:

```js
const dateStamp = (inputFunc) => {

    let todayDate = new Date()
    console.log(todayDate)

    let newObj = {};

    return function (num) {
        newObj.date = todayDate;
        newObj.output = inputFunc(num);
        return newObj;
    }
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
const stampedMultBy2 = dateStamp(n => n * 2);
    
console.log(stampedMultBy2(4)); // should log: { date: (today's date), output: 8 }
console.log(stampedMultBy2(6)); // should log: { date: (today's date), output: 12 }
```

My code fails two test specs:

[image]

My questions are:

> 1. how do I take timestamp out of current date
> 2. why is last spec failing?

Comment: For the first error, use [.toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString), i,e, `newObj.date = todayDate.toDateString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** For the first error, you can use [Date.toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) to get only the date part (without time) of today's date.

**2)** The second error I believe is related to the fact that you are not taking into account that the returned function can accept a number of variable arguments. For solve this, you can declare it as:

```
return function (...args) { ... };
```

And then, when calling the received function use `inputFunc(...args)`. In summary, you can go with the next approach:

```js
const dateStamp = (inputFunc) =>
{
    let todayDate = new Date();

    return (...args) =>
    {
        return {
            date: todayDate.toDateString(),
            output: inputFunc(...args)
        }
    }
}

const stampedMultBy2 = dateStamp(n => n * 2);
console.log(stampedMultBy2(4));
console.log(stampedMultBy2(6));

const stampedMax = dateStamp((x, y) => Math.max(x, y));
console.log(stampedMax(-5, 6));
console.log(stampedMax(1, 4));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

You can even shorten the `dateStamp` function this way using the *arrow notation*:

```
const dateStamp = (inputFunc) => (...args) =>
    ({date: (new Date()).toDateString(), output: inputFunc(...args)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes num as a value. It should take a function as the value. Then your output field of the newObj should be the result of evaluating the function passed to the function.

```
newObj.output = func()
```